# Segue is not being performed

Tags: ios, swift

I've created a method for auto login via Firebase but somehow my segue is not being performed..

I've this code and in my viewDidLoad I'm calling the method (ofc)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

  //Login user automatically
  autoLogin()
}

func autoLogin(){
    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.email != nil{

        print("not nil") //for test
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toRootVc", sender: self)
        print("not nil1") //for test
    }
    else{
        print("nil") //for test
    }
}
```

> The app prints both "not nil" and "not nil1" but it still does not
>   performing the segue.

I also have a login button which works.

```
func handleLogin(){
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!) { (result, err) in
        if let err = err{
            print("Error logging in:", err.localizedDescription)
        }
        else{
            self.databaseHandler.retrieveData(email: self.email.text!){
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toRootVc", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the autoLogin doesn't actually performing the segue. (Ignores the step)

Any input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segues won't work inside `viewDidLoad` as it's too early try in `viewWillAppear` or better do this check before presenting that vc say inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of `AppDelegate`

Comment: I can't perform a segue in didFinishLaunching right?

Comment: no segue there you can create an instance of the destination vc and assign it to `window?.rootViewController`

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. So, that will load even faster, right?

Comment: Do you have any more specific example of your AppDelegate example?

Comment: I'm getting: "Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'window'"

Comment: I guess that's located in the SceneDelegate nowadays, hmmm

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to put this autoLogin() on viewDidAppear()

Comment: `viewDidAppear` is a bad place as the login vc will appear for some small time

Comment: That does work. But as @Sh_Khan says, the login vc does appear for a millisecond.